# PapaParse - Want to ensure Chunks processed in sequence. Apex response need to fire next processing sequence

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components, csv

How can i ensure when first Chunk inserted in SF then need to fire second chunk  to make sure sequential processing? I am able to chunk the records in SF and format accordingly but need to insert records in chunks as i process at client side in sequence.

```
Papa.parse(file, {
worker: true,
chunkSize: 1024 * 5,
chunk: function (results) {
    this.papaRecords = results.data;
    let lstCCToInsert = [];
    var obj = {};
    obj = this.papaRecords;

    lstCCToInsert.push(obj);
    RecordInsertJob({
        lstCCToInsert: lstCCToInsert,
    })
        .then(result => {
            thiss.status = result; // when first Chunk inserted in SF then need to fire second chunk ?
        })
        .catch((error) => {

        });

},
complete: function () {
    console.log('Complete');

} 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a queue for the data:

```
dataInsertQueue = [];
```

And papaparse should put those records in the queue:

```
this.dataInsertQueue.push(results.data);
this.pumpQueue();
```

Where pumpQueue() checks if there's any pending work and not already busy:

```
pendingUpload = false;
pumpQueue() {
  if(!pendingUpload && this.dataInsertQueue.length) {
    this.uploadToServer();
  }
}
```

And finally, sending to the server:

```
uploadToServer() {
  if(this.dataUploadQueue.length) {
    this.pendingUpload = true;
    RecordInsertJob({
      lstCCToInsert: this.dataUploadQueue.shift(),
    })
    .then(result => {
      this.status = result;
      this.pendingUpload = false;
      this.pumpQueue();
    })
  }
}
```

In other words, you should have a FIFO (First In, First Out) queue to process the records.

You'll need to do some additional cleanup, as presumably the status value should state how many records are in total, successful, and errored. I leave this as an exercise to you; it should be possible to figure it out once you've gotten this far.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. Addition to your suggestion , Parser.pause() and Parser.resume() did the magic to process chunk by chunk.